# Two accounts caused loss of votes

Tags: support, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I registered on StackOverflow and GameDev with the same gmail address.
For some reason I ended up with two user names. I was tolerating this for a while. Yesterday I answered a question on GameDev and got a few votes for it. Then it was rightly moved to StackOverflow and my user name there doesn't make sense. I think the votes are no longer attributed to either of my two accounts.

Could I get the votes added to my stack overflow account (this user name) and then get the accounts merged? The question is:

[Deleting a derived object via a pointer to its base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772227/deleting-a-derived-object-via-a-pointer-to-its-base-class#22038)

Closed:Thanks to everybody who wored at this.

Comment: Email the team (team@stackoverflow.com) and ask to merge those accounts. Give them your email address and they'll merge all accounts associated with it.

Comment: Beware, @Shadow: *"To merge multiple accounts within a specific site, or registered accounts between two different websites, email is no longer the preferred method of handling this, since the dev team has many other things to do."*, according to [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Comment: @Arjan good catch, didn't know flagging is better for this. Mr. Blaster - if you didn't send mail already, follow the other steps first. :-)

Comment: I have sent the mail but I am will try those instructions also. It says "flag your post for moderator attention and ask for a merge" I'm not sure how to do that. It mentions "mod flag" ?

Comment: Just wait a bit, @ScrollerBlaster. No need to have two people look at it, and then confuse one if the first already took care of it. (For other future users, I will edit that answer to make "mod flag" more clear.)

Comment: I emailed the team for a merge once and waited for about 5 days - so be patient.. don't worry nothing will be lost and all your data (answers, upvotes etc) will be preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just merge your accounts which:

- Combined your two accounts
- Mapped that post to your combined account
- Recalced your rep to show the +50 from the migrated answer

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that one of the accounts meets the requirements (low rep/unregistered, will elaborate), emailing the team is *not* the preferred method to do this, as mods can do it with ease.

Here are the preferred steps to getting accounts merged:

- On the account you want to be the "master" account, place a statement in the profile section stating "I wish this to be the master account for the following accounts" and then place **links** to the user accounts that are to be merged with that master account
- On the accounts that are to be merged with the "master" account, place a statement in the profile section stating "I wish for this to me merged with the following account" along with a **single** link to the master account
- Flag a question/answer for moderator attention using *one* of the accounts, choose "other" as a reason, and in the custom message box say "I'd like my accounts merged, I've provided all of the relevant links in my profiles"

Note that links are a must since user names are not unique. You can substitute the account IDs for links above but that's just more work for everyone (including the user making these changes)

If you do this, the mod can then figure out what profiles should be merged and then what profile is the "master" one which will keep the user-provided details after the merge.

Putting the links/IDs in the "about me" section is reasonable proof that it's the same user (granted, two users could collaborate and have this done, but that would be foolish and we'd more than likely separate them in the event we found out).

Comment: As this is slightly different from the FAQ at [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist), I guess that FAQ needs updating?

Comment: I think most people have two accounts as they have lost access to one of them due to cookies timeing out etc, so editing both accounts will not work in a lot of cases.